# sum over inputs of three arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, sum

I have 3 arrays named R, p and k and i also have an expression.
I want to compute this expression for the first value of R and the whole values of p and k.
then sum all the result obtained from this step and put them into a new array as the first element.
Then compute the mentioned expression for the second value of R and every values of p and k. Then, again sum all the results of the second step and put them into a new array as the second element and so on ...
I do some coding but I don't know how to continue it.
I would appreciate it if you help me.

```
import numpy as np
R = [1,4,6]
p = [6,4,1]
k = [8,5,2]
sigma = np.zeros(len(R))
for i in range(len(R)):
    for j in range(len(k)):
        sigma = (p[j]+k[j]*R[i])
        print(sigma)
```

How can I sum the values resulted from first (second etc,) R and append them into a new array?

Comment: It might help people understand what you are trying to do if you add the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using list comprehensions.

It's basically translated as, for each i in R, calculate sigma for each pair  in p,k

```
R = [1,4,6]
p = [6,4,1]
k = [8,5,2]

[[a+b*i for a,b in zip(p,k)] for i in R]
```

Output

```
[[14, 9, 3], [38, 24, 9], [54, 34, 13]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
R = [1,4,6]
p = [6,4,1]
k = [8,5,2]
ans = np.zeros(len(R))
for i in range(len(R)):
    sigma = 0 #for each value in R  calculated value initialized to 0
    for j in range(len(k)):
        #loop through second array and compute the expression
        sigma += p[j]+k[j]*R[i]
    ans[i]=sigma #add value to answers list after second loop
print(ans)
```